# Bullet not colliding with enemy Pygame (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to make a mega man similar game where you jump around and shooting stuff. But I've noticed there's something wrong with the collision, I have a video below:

https://youtu.be/p2VCtbBkefo

I'm planning to make this project open source, so anybody can customize it. Please don't steal this code, but you may use chunks of it to help you with something. because I haven't put it on GitHub publicly yet.

main.py:

```
import pygame as pg
from player import *
from settings import *
from levels import *
from block import *
from enemy import *

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        pg.mixer.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((width, height))
        pg.display.set_caption("wait until realesed.")
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.enemiesList = []
        self.running = True
        self.shootRight = True

    def loadLevel(self, level, enemies, group, group2, group3):

        for y in range(0, len(level)):
            for x in range(0, len(level[y])):
                if (level[y][x] == 1):
                    blockList.append(Block(x*32, y*32))
                    group.add(Block(x*32, y*32))
                    group2.add(Block(x*32, y*32))

        for amount in range(0, enemies):
            group2.add(FlyingEnemy(self))
            group3.add(FlyingEnemy(self))
            self.enemies.add(FlyingEnemy(self))
            self.enemiesList.append(FlyingEnemy(self))

    def new(self):

        self.platforms = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.enemies = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.bullets = pg.sprite.Group()

        self.player = Player()
        self.loadLevel(level1["platform"], level1["enemies"], self.platforms, self.all_sprites, self.enemies)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.player)
        self.run()

    def shoot(self):
        if self.shootRight:
            self.bullet = Bullet(self.player.rect.centerx, self.player.rect.centery)
            self.bullet.speed = 10
            self.all_sprites.add(self.bullet)
            self.bullets.add(self.bullet)
            print(self.bullet)
        elif self.shootRight == False:
            self.bullet = Bullet(self.player.rect.centerx, self.player.rect.centery)
            self.bullet.speed = -10
            self.all_sprites.add(self.bullet)
            self.bullets.add(self.bullet)
            print(self.bullet)


    def run(self):

        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.clock.tick(FPS)
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def update(self):
        self.all_sprites.update()

        self.enemy_hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.enemies, False)

        #print(enemy_hits)
        if self.enemy_hits:
            pass
            #print("hit")
        self.bullet_hits = pg.sprite.groupcollide(self.enemies, self.bullets, True, True)

        if self.bullet_hits:
            print(self.bullet_hits)
            pygame.quit()





        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.platforms, False)

        if hits:
            self.player.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top + 1
            self.player.vel.y = 0

    def events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                if self.playing:
                    self.playing = False
                    self.running = false
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_UP:
                    self.player.jump()
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    self.shoot()
                if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                    self.shootRight = True
                if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                    self.shootRight = False



    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
        pg.display.flip()

    def show_start_screen(self):
        pass
    def show_go_screen(self):
        pass

g = Game()
g.show_start_screen()
while g.running:
    g.new()
    g.show_go_screen()

pg.quit()


"""width = 800
height = 600
FPS = 60

pg.init()
pg.mixer.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((width, height))
pg.display.set_caption("doom room")
clock = pg.time.Clock()


running = True

while running:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        clock.tick(FPS)
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = false

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pg.display.flip()

pg.quit()"""


    import pygame

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image  = pygame.Surface((20, 10))
        self.image.fill((240, 43, 12))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speed = -10

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speed

        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()
```

player.py

```
    import pygame as pg
from settings import *
from laser import *
vec = pg.math.Vector2

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((40, 40))
        self.image.fill((80, 123, 255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (width / 2, height / 2)
        self.pos = vec(width / 2, height / 2)
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)
        #self.vx = 0
        #self.vy = 0

    def jump(self):
        self.vel.y = -15



    def update(self):

        self.acc = vec(0, player_gravity)
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT]:
            self.acc.x = -player_acc
        if keys[pg.K_RIGHT]:
            self.acc.x = player_acc

        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * player_friction
        self.vel += self.acc
        self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc

        if self.pos.x > width:
            self.pos.x = 0
        if self.pos.x < 0:
            self.pos.x = width
        if self.pos.y <= 0:
            self.pos.y += 15

        self.rect.midbottom = self.pos
```

enemy.py

```
    import pygame as pg
from random import *
from settings import *
class FlyingEnemy(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((45, 45))
        self.image.fill((20, 203, 50))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = choice([-100, width + 100])
        self.vx = randrange(4, 7)
        if self.rect.centerx > width:
            self.vx *= -1
        self.rect.y = height / 4
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.vy = 0
        self.dy = 0.5



    def update(self):
        if self.rect.x > width:
            self.rect.x = 0
        if self.rect.x < 0:
            self.rect.x = width

        self.rect.x += self.vx
        self.vy += self.dy
        if self.vy > 3 or self.vy < -3:
            self.dy *= -1
        center = self.rect.center
        if self.dy < 0:
            pass
            #print("bobbed up")
        else:
            pass
            #print("bobbed down")
```

settings.py

```
import pygame

blockList = []


player_acc = 1.0
player_friction = -0.12
player_gravity = 0.5

bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

true = True
false = False
width = 800
height = 600
FPS = 60
```

levels.py

```
level1 = {

"platform": [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],

],
"enemies": 5

}
```

block.py

```
import pygame as pg

class Block(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

Thanks all help is appreciated.

Comment: `Please don't steal this code` -> This made me smile. I mean, it's really great to learn and to try to improve, but... you know, there's a lot of free/open-source source code for games out there, and I doubt someone will ever be interested in *stealing* the partial sources of the prototype of a game... Anyway, I'm thinking about your issue :)

Comment: Ok Right Leg, I'll take that in account. : )

Comment: where is the part of your code that manages collisions?

Comment: Please don't post your complete project here. We just want a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the `loadLevel` method causes the problem:

```
for amount in range(0, enemies):
    group2.add(FlyingEnemy(self))
    group3.add(FlyingEnemy(self))
    self.enemies.add(FlyingEnemy(self))
    self.enemiesList.append(FlyingEnemy(self))
```

You're adding 4 different `FlyingEnemy` objects to these groups and the list (btw, the list is useless), so the sprites in the `self.all_sprites` group and in the `self.enemies` group are not the same.

Since you're only updating the `all_sprites` and not the `enemies`, the sprites in the `enemies` group, which are used for the collision detection, stay at the left screen edge all the time and are also invisible, because you don't draw this group.

To solve the problem, create one instance and add this instance to the two groups:

```
for amount in range(0, enemies):
    enemy = FlyingEnemy(self)
    self.enemies.add(enemy)
    self.all_sprites.add(enemy)
```

---

I found the bug by printing the rect of one enemy sprite in the `self.enemies` group. Then I checked the `update` method of this sprite, but it looked correct, so I went to the instantiation part in `loadLevel` and noticed the mistake.

Comment: Thanks very much skrx, you saved me alot of time.